# Angularjs: Not loading a view every time

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs app that has a menu on top of it. When the user navigates in the menu the view gets changed with the $location command. Each view has its own controller.

I would like to keep some views "alive" after changing the view in the menu, that way when the user goes back to the previous view it is in the same state and with the same data.

How could I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solutions below are good, a third option requiring far less code would be configuring `$http` to cache responses (as appropriate for your app). That way, when you return to a view, the data that was previously retrieved from the server will be retrieved from the cache. You get this for free just by setting `cache: true`. Where it makes sense, you can remove data from the cache so Angular will retrieve it from the server the next time. Depending on your app, your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are probably what you need.

You may hit a service which has for only purpose to store data for your controllers.

```
angular
    .module('foo')
    .service('ContextualDataService', function () {
        'use strict';

        var data = {},
            storageIdentity = 'contextualDataService';
        return {
            get: function (key) {
                return data[key];
            },
            set: function (key, value) {
                data[key] = value;
            },
            save: function () {
                localStorage.setItem(storageIdentity, JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            load: function () {
                 var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageIdentity));

                 if (items) {
                      for (var key in items) {
                           data[key] = items[key];
                      }
                 }
            }
        };
});
```

And later you can use it and isolate you controllers or anything as a namespace

```
angular
    .module('foo')
    .controller('BarController', ['ContextualDataService', function (context) {
        var myData = context.get('foo.controllers.bar.savedKey') || 'myDefaultSavedKeyValue';

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you could use the browser's local storage to store data on the page you want to keep when reloading it.

Check at this:
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Basically, in the controller of the concerned page, if data is present in **local storage**, you build the page rendering from them, otherwise, page with the default values will be displayed.

As soon as a change is made by the user on this page, you update the concerned set of data in the local storage.

Be aware, that you may want to clear the local storage at any time, perhaps when user has just been disconnected.

Personally, I use it to save the state of the search filters about a list of items, during the whole user navigation.

You may be interested by the introduction of local storage in HTML 5: 
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html